# J++ to J#: how to convert resources?

Tags: .net, embedded-resource, j#, j++, visualj#

I have a *Visual J++* project which I want to migrate to *J#*. The code doesn't use any Microsoft-specific API (like *WFC*) or non-standard language extensions, so, technically, it is fully Java 1.1 compliant.

The only problem are resources (which in Java world are usually accessed using the [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa282271%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) API).

In *J++*, it was sufficient to specify the resource filename patterns in the project configuration, and all the resources matched by patterns would have been embedded into the resulting *.exe (as native Win32 resources) and accessible both programmatically using `Class.getResourceAsStream()` and manually using any [resource editor](https://stefansundin.github.io/xn_resource_editor/):

[image]

#### The problem

Once the project was migrated to *Visual J#* (VS 2005), I immediately lost the ability to load any resources (`Class.getResourceAsStream()` started returning `null` values), despite the "Build Action" setting was set to "Embedded Resource" for each resource of interest:

[image]

and the resources actually get embedded into the assembly (can be confirmed by the increased *.exe file size; additionally, I do see those resources using the [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) tool). The unique resource name is generated using the following pattern:

`<assembly's default namespace>.<Java package>.<file name with extension>`

so if I had a file named `README.txt` nested under the `com.example` package, the resulting assembly resource name will be `default.com.example.README.txt`:

[image: dotPeek]

*Visual Studio 2003* behaves differently from the 2005 version: `Class.getResourceAsStream()` doesn't return any `null` but an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown by `mscorlib.dll` at run time:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.String.Substring(int startIndex = 0, int length = -1) + 0xbb bytes  
vjslib.dll!com.ms.vjsharp.lang.VJSClassLoader.__findResource(System.Reflection.Assembly currentAssembly = {System.Reflection.Assembly}, string resName = "com/example/README.txt") + 0xc5 bytes 
vjslib.dll!com.ms.vjsharp.lang.VJSClassLoader.__getResourcefromAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly callingAssembly = {System.Reflection.Assembly}, string resName = "com.example.Main/+/com/example/README.txt") + 0x1b7 bytes  
vjslib.dll!com.ms.vjsharp.lang.VJSClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(string resName = "com.example.Main/+/com/example/README.txt") + 0x57 bytes    
vjslib.dll!java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(string resourceName = "com.example.Main/+/com/example/README.txt") + 0x10d bytes 
test-resource-loading.exe!com.example.Main.main(String[] args = {Length=0}) Line 21 + 0x26 bytes
```

-- but I believe this is just a bug that was fixed in the 2.0 version of the *.NET Framework*.

`com.ms.vjsharp.lang.VJSClassLoader` apparently is not a public class for me to be able to play with it directly.

#### Workarounds attempted

1. Replace the relative resource path with the absolute one, dots with slashes and vice versa, with or w/o the leading slash, with or w/o the default assembly namespace prepended -- no effect.
2. Compile the whole project into an executable *.jar using a `javac` compiler and feed the resulting JAR to *J# Binary Converter Tool* (`jbimp.exe`) -- not an option. *J# Binary Converter Tool* is almost useless due to its limitations (I tried both versions -- from VS 2003 and VS 2005):

   - a single call to `Class.getResourceAsStream(...)` in Java bytecode results in `System.InvalidProgramException` thrown at runtime, despite bytecode to MSIL conversion is successful.
   - whenever there's a try-finally block (which is how stream I/O is usually done in *Java*), `jbimp.exe` fails with these messages (I gave up trying to rewrite the 5-line block of code which was merely reading from a file):

     ```
     JbImp error: Internal Conversion Error : 'exc-unclosed-blocks'
     JbImp error: Failed to create type for class 'com/example/Main'. Creating stub type
     JbImp error: Internal Conversion Error : 'JbImp fatal error: Conversion failed'
     ```
3. *J++ Project Migration Wizard* from VS 2003/2005 is not helpful: it simply ignores any resources which are not referenced from a `*.rc`/`*.res` file.
4. Manually create a `*.resx` file, add all resources to it and get rid of `Class.getResourceAsStream()` calls entirely (change the Java code to load resources as `System.String` (for text) and `System.Drawing.Bitmap` (for images)). This is the only working approach, but if you have dozens of small `*.gif` files in your project, it becomes really tedious.

#### The question

Why doesn't the `vjslib.dll` implementation of `Class.getResourceAsStream()` work as expected? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While *Microsoft*'s documentation for *Java* API implemented in *J#* runtime is vague (particularly, the page for [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa987898%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) states that, unlike *J++*, this method is not supported in *J#*), there *is* a solution.

Further research shows that, apart from custom [class loaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2xt6f4d(v=vs.80).aspx) (which have been dropped), all of *Java* **1.1** and even some of *Java* **1.2** API has been implemented -- including [*collections*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abw7x2tf(v=vs.80).aspx) and [*Swing*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k12dt1e0(v=vs.80).aspx).

Speaking of *resources*, those are covered by the [How to: Upgrade Visual J++ 6.0 Applications That Use Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2650xc(v=vs.80).aspx) article. *Java*-style resources can be converted to `.resx` using the [`vjsresgen.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9ca18e5(v=vs.80).aspx) utility which comes with *Visual Studio 2005* application samples, with source code available from *Microsoft*.

Each resource is converted into a byte array. Here's the screenshot of a sample `vjsresgen.exe`-generated `.resx` file opened in *Visual Studio*:

[image: vjsresgen.exe-generated .resx file]